# Regex to replace non escaped Quotes

Tags: php, regex

After having some trouble building a `json` string I discovered some text in my database containing double quotes. I need to replace the quotes with their escaped equivalents. This works:

```
function escape( $str ) {
    return preg_replace('/"/',"\\\"",$str);
}
```

but it doesn't take into account that a quote may already be escaped. How can I modify the expression so that it's only true only for a non escaped character?

Comment: This is to help you with your other `regex` question: http://regex101.com/r/mX0qH5 By the time I went to post... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a *negative lookbehind* here

```
function escape( $str ) {
    return preg_replace('/(?<!\\)"/',"\\\"",$str);
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that. About the other question, this site really gets to me sometimes, all the downvotes and closevotes... all without explanation. It gives me the impression people just downvote for the hell of it. Anyway, sorry for the rant. I figured out where to place a positive lookahead and got it working. Slightly changed `/^.*?(?:(?<!\\)(?:(?P<end>}\s*)|(?P<nest>{[!#]?\s*))|(?=\\$)|$)/sm`

Comment: @Waldermort, Ah, I missed that you wanted to match till `$` but *excluding* it. That lookahead makes sense. Good to know you got it working.

Comment: This is insufficient. If two backslashes precede the `"`, it's not escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Try first remove the '\' from all escaped doube-quotes, than escape all double-quotes.

```
str_replace(array('\"', '"'), array('"', '\"'), $str);
```

Comment: But what about text like `Hello\\"World` which is preceeded with an escaped slash?

Answer (score 0):

Try `preg_replace('/([^\\\])"/', '$1\\"', $str);`

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this will work](https://regex101.com/r/Ni9GFk/1)

regex:

```
(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)"
```

code:

```
$re = '/(?<!\\\\)((?:\\\\\\\\)*)"/';
preg_replace($re, '$1\\"', 'foo"bar'); // foo\"bar -- slash added
preg_replace($re, '$1\\"', 'foo\\"bar'); // foo\"bar -- already escaped, nothing added
preg_replace($re, '$1\\"', 'foo\\\\"bar'); // foo\\\"bar -- not escaped, extra slash added
```